# Why didn't the timer call the selector?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func countDownForGetVerify(sender: NSTimer) {
    verifyBtn.setTitle("(\(Int(kVerityTime))s)", forState: .Disabled)
    kVerityTime--
    if kVerityTime == 0 {
        stopCountDown()
    }
}

private func startCountDown() {
    timer.fireDate = NSDate.distantPast()
}

private func stopCountDown() {
    kVerityTime = 60
    timer.fireDate = NSDate.distantFuture()
    verifyBtn.enabled = true
}


// MARK: - Lazy initial
private var timer: NSTimer {
    get {
        return NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "countDownForGetVerify", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: just add ':' after method name countDownForGetVerify:

Answer (score 4):

Because there is a trailing colon missing (representing the parameter)

```
"countDownForGetVerify:"
```

Comment: Oops,my fault Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

whenever u write any selector ,specify colon at the end always
so replace this line

```
"NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "countDownForGetVerify", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

with this

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "countDownForGetVerify:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```